# React Native React - _this2.SetState is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the following error even though I'm doing the bind "_this2.SetState is not a function

Here is my code

```
// Subscribers to selected team change
        const subToNewDataChange = subscribe('newData', state => {
            const random = Math.random() * (100 - 15) + 15;
            // Updates the state with the connection change and re renders the view
            this.setState({key:random }, function () {
                this.forceUpdate();
            }.bind(this));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the subscription was happening each time on component mount, i.e. subToConnectionChange was getting created over and over and the reason that this just starting to happen was that removed the entire view form react navigation tabbar when the view was inside a tabbar it would only load once.